# Terrain does not show up in distance in play mode, but does in editor

Tags: camera, terrain, settings

I'm trying to make a big landscape with high mountains but the terrain doesn't show in the distance in play mode.

Which settings should I change, or what can I do?

My terrain is divided in many pieces - do I have to change all of these terrains or is there any other option?

Comment: Is this in Unity? If so, please tag your question accordingly. Have you tried adjusting the far plane of your camera?

Comment: unity! yes its working now :) thanks

Comment: Want to share your solution as an Answer then so this question has some closure?